# Child window has 2 diffrent parents from 2 different applications

Tags: javascript

I have 2 parent windows(a.js & b.js) in 2 different applications(no security origing issues). They both open same child window(c.js).  In a.js the child window is opened with

```
function a(empid){
    window.showModalDialog("c.jsp", self, "dialogWidth:200px;dialogHeight:200px;scroll:no;help:no;status:no;");
    }
    function parentRefresh(){
                    size.refresh();
    }
```

in `b.js` the c`.js` is opnened with `window.open`

```
function b(){
window.open(someurl,"empinfo", width=1050,height=700,left=0,top=0);
}
function getEmpinfo(empId){
}
```

in `c.js`

```
var parentWin // this refers to a.js
function closeParents(){
if(window.opener.parent.document.title=="AAA" && !window.opener.closed){                     
                        window.opener.getEmpinfo(empId);
                        window.close();
                   }else{                
                        parentWin.setTimeout("parentRefresh()", 1);
                        self.close();
                   }
}
<body scroll="no" onload="load();" onbeforeunload="closeParents();">
```

parent a.js and child c.js are in the same application. b.js is in different application. it works fine when I open C.js from b.js(it gets the method in b.js) but it does not get the method parentRefresh(). I am not sure if it beacuse one parent open with window.open and the other with showModaldialog. I cannot change showmodaldialog to window.open. Any ideas? i can only use javascript, no jquery. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `window.showModalDialog` is highly deprecated and will be turned off by all supporting browsers during the next month. Chrome is already no longer supporting this, FF will follow shortly. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog)

Comment: I am aware of that issue. I need it to work for IE only. If you know how to solve this in IE, please let me know. Thanks.